# Wordpress Plugins - Can't find the part that controls the output

Tags: php, wordpress

I just recently downloaded and installed the WP-PostViews Plugin by Lester Chan:

Plugin Name: WP-PostViews
Plugin URI: http://lesterchan.net/portfolio/programming/php/
Where to download: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/

In any case, I have added the plugin's widget to my sidebar, below 'The Latest' and 'Most Popular', as seen in http://test.scninja.com . I gave it the title/name 'test views'.

What I am trying to do is find where within the plugin's .php file is the set of instructions that determine the info output so that I can format said appropriately. Right now, it's just spitting out an `<a>` with the post title and link followed by '- # Views' in plain text after the closure of the `<a>` tag. I would like to remove the dash, add a class to '# views' and so forth in order to fully customize the look of my site.

For some reason the plugin's php code is breaking out of the code tags here so I uploaded it as a txt file to my server: http://test.scninja.com/wp-postviews.txt

All help is appreciated

Sotkra

Comment: You just had to search for a fragment of the HTML to find it. " - " (the dash surrounded by spaces) would've been a good start.

Comment: Ofc I did that and applied the changes, but as I mentioned below, after removing the dash as a test - saving changes and then reloading the page. Surprise surprise, the dash is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the fifth from last line of the file.

```
$views_options['most_viewed_template'] = '<li><a href="%POST_URL%"  title="%POST_TITLE%">%POST_TITLE%</a> - %VIEW_COUNT% '.__('views', 'wp-postviews').'</li>';
```

Comment: Apparently not, I edited that line, refreshed the page and nothing changed. To be precise, I removed, as a mere test, the dash preceding the number of views variable. After saving the changes and refreshing the page, the dash is still there.

Comment: You can override the template in the plugin's options. You probably have something else set there.

Comment: I don't know which plugin options you're referring to Dan:

A) Plugin's Widget Config Options in the WP Admin Panel (neither make reference to the output template)...so no

B) Plugin's options extra php page (postviews-options.php) within the plugin's folder (says disabled in the wordpress admin plugin editor)...so prolly not either

C) Plugin's options within the core .php file itself...making reference to overriding the template...not sure what those instructions would look like though

Comment: I'm talking about the PostViews options page in your wp-admin, which has the HTML for this output right on the page when you click it. I checked. It's a menu item on the left hand side of your wp-admin, not a file to edit. Go into your wp-admin and change it.

Comment: Woah jeez, never saw that =/. I mistakenly assumed it contained no major wp-admin features and here I am as a result =(.
That solved the problem, thanks A LOT DAN, really, I owe you one.

Comment: I didn't notice either until I installed the plugin and looked myself